# Performance Profiling not generating reports in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, profiling

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with Update 4. When I run performance profiling( from  DEBUG> Performance and Diagnostics> Performance Wizard> CPU Sampling,
the profiler starts and stops without errors. But no reports are generated. When I tried to open the report from Performance Explorer an error message pops up showing:

***"Invalid report: the data in the file is corrupt or has an unsupported format"***.

I tried searching for solutions, but I could only find solutions for VS2015 and 2017( I tried them by relating it to the functionalities in VS2013 but no result).

Comment: Can you update to a more recent version of Visual Studio? What OS are you on? Some versions of Windows no longer support how profiling was carried out in earlier versions of VS. Some more info on that can be found at: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/221378/visual-studio-2017-profiler-for-c-is-completely-br.html

Comment: I am using Windows 10 Pro version:10.0.17134. I tried profiling with VS2017. It works. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tried profiling with Visual Studio 2017. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure but I think there is an incompatibility issue if you installed a newer version of Visual Studio on your computer.

Try to open the report generated (that fails to open in VS2013) in your newer Visual Studio. That did the trick for me with VS2017.